# Getting an Error for Postgresql external database binding with Keycloak operator v21.1.1

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-custom-resources, keycloak-operator

This is challenge from keycloak when I am declaring the external database in keycloak kubernetes custom resource based on it's crd that I got from keycloak-operator installation from https://operatorhub.io/operator/keycloak-operator

This is the Keycloak custom resource I am using for keycloak instance and binding external postgresql db :-

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: keycloak-prod
spec:
  instances: 1
  db:
    vendor: postgresql
    url: jdbc:postgresql://aksdev-pgdb.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/keycloakdevDB
    host: aksdev-pgdb.postgres.database.azure.com
    database: keycloakdevDB
    port: 5432
    schema: public
    usernameSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: username
    passwordSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: password
```

After applying this resource, the pod stucks in CrashLoopBackOff state and throws such logs:-

$ *kubectl logs keycloak-prod-0 -n my-keycloak-operator*

Changes detected in configuration.Updating the server image.
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
The DelayedHandler was closed before any children handlers were configured. Messages will be written to stderr.
2023-06-07 06:18:19,820 DEBUG [org.jboss.logging] (main) Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerProvider

2023-06-07 06:18:20,479 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement [org.keycloak:keycloak-quarkus-server / runtime=true resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-06-07 06:18:20,481 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http / runtime=true resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-06-07 06:18:20,722 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json-deployment / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-06-07 06:18:20,722 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-gelf-deployment / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-06-07 06:18:20,722 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[org.keycloak:keycloak-quarkus-server-deployment / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD
.
.
.

2023-06-07 06:18:21,203 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[/ runtime=true resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Deployment Class Loader: PROD

2023-06-07 06:18:21,212 DEBUG [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Beginning Quarkus augmentation

2023-06-07 06:18:21,487 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@57ac5227

2023-06-07 06:18:21,488 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@57ac5227

ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: No value present

---

What might be the reason? which value this error is talking about?

Comment: It is solved by correcting vendor value from postgresql to postgres. Also I was getting challenge with Java security ERROR: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA.

For that I disable the ssl of my database as it was in off state there by editing jdbc connection url in keycloak custom resource:-  
url: jdbc:postgresql://aksdev-pgdb.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/keycloakdevDb?sslmode=disable